# TypeError no Python, preciso modificar um string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um tabuleiro de xadrez bem simples sem nenhum regra, apenas modifico as posições para jogar.
Fiz um lista com as casa disponíveis no tabuleiro e com a função mover eu altero as posições,enfim, ainda ta bem simples. o problema é que eu não consigo alterar a posição anterior para uma vazia, evitando que as peças se dupliquem.
recebo o erro:

```
boardnumFrom[positionFrom] = '[]'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

preciso definir as posições de saída da peça para uma casa vazia e não sei como.
Codigo do tabuleiro:

```
board8 = {
    'a8': [], 'b8': [], 'c8': [], 'd8': [], 'e8': [], 'f8': [], 'g8': [], 'h8': []
}
board7 = {
    'a7': [], 'b7': [], 'c7': [], 'd7': [], 'e7': [], 'f7': [], 'g7': [], 'h7': []
}
board6 = {
    'a6': [], 'b6': [], 'c6': [], 'd6': [], 'e6': [], 'f6': [], 'g6': [], 'h6': []
}
board5 = {
    'a5': [], 'b5': [], 'c5': [], 'd5': [], 'e5': [], 'f5': [], 'g5': [], 'h5': []
}
board4 = {
    'a4': [], 'b4': [], 'c4': [], 'd4': [], 'e4': [], 'f4': [], 'g4': [], 'h4': []
}
board3 = {
    'a3': [], 'b3': [], 'c3': [], 'd3': [], 'e3': [], 'f3': [], 'g3': [], 'h3': []
}
board2 = {
    'a2': [], 'b2': [], 'c2': [], 'd2': [], 'e2': [], 'f2': [], 'g2': [], 'h2': []
}
board1 = {
    'a1': [], 'b1': [], 'c1': [], 'd1': [], 'e1': [], 'f1': [], 'g1': [], 'h1': []
}


def setBoard():
    # white
    board1['a1'] = 'T'
    board1['b1'] = 'B'
    board1['c1'] = 'N'
    board1['d1'] = 'Q'
    board1['e1'] = 'K'
    board1['f1'] = 'N'
    board1['g1'] = 'B'
    board1['h1'] = 'T'
    board2['a2'] = 'P'
    board2['b2'] = 'P'
    board2['c2'] = 'P'
    board2['d2'] = 'P'
    board2['e2'] = 'P'
    board2['f2'] = 'P'
    board2['g2'] = 'P'
    board2['h2'] = 'P'
    # black
    board8['a8'] = 'T'
    board8['b8'] = 'B'
    board8['c8'] = 'N'
    board8['d8'] = 'K'
    board8['e8'] = 'Q'
    board8['f8'] = 'N'
    board8['g8'] = 'B'
    board8['h8'] = 'T'
    board7['a7'] = 'P'
    board7['b7'] = 'P'
    board7['c7'] = 'P'
    board7['d7'] = 'P'
    board7['e7'] = 'P'
    board7['f7'] = 'P'
    board7['g7'] = 'P'
    board7['h7'] = 'P'

while True:

    def mover(boardnumFrom, boardnumTo, positionFrom, positionTo):
        boardnumFrom[positionFrom] = '[]'
        boardnumTo[positionTo] = piece


    def start():
        setBoard()
        print(board8)
        print(board7)
        print(board6)
        print(board5)
        print(board4)
        print(board3)
        print(board2)
        print(board1)


    start()
    piece = input("""
Digite 'sair' ou digite 
Qual peça deseja mover? 
>""")
    if (piece == 'sair'):
        print('Adeus, obrigado por jogar.')
        break
    else:
        boardnumFrom = input('Qual fileira voce esta? ')
        boardnumTo = input('Para qual fileira voce vai? ')
        positionFrom = input('Qual casa voce esta? ')
        positionTo = input('Para qual casa voce vai? ')
        mover(boardnumFrom, boardnumTo, positionFrom, positionTo)
```

é grande mas é bem simples.

Comment: Minha recomendação pra vc eh usar matriz ao invés de vários dicionários.. Vai ser mais fácil de fazer o que vc quer.. (um ex de vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EGmlFdwD4C4)

Answer (score 1):

Ao fazer:

```
boardnumFrom = input('Qual fileira voce esta? ')
```

A variável `boardnumFrom` será uma string, pois é isso que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) retorna. Depois, você passa essa string para a função `mover`:

```
mover(boardnumFrom, boardnumTo, positionFrom, positionTo)
```

E dentro desta função, tenta mudar uma posição desta string:

```
boardnumFrom[positionFrom] = '[]'
```

Só que em Python [strings são imutáveis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) e você não pode mudar nenhuma posição da mesma. Qualquer tentativa de fazê-lo dará esse erro que você viu. Ex:

```
s = 'uma string qualquer'
s[1] = 'x' # TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

---

Enfim, essa é a causa do erro. Dito isso, acho que você deveria rever tudo que está fazendo.

Primeiro, o tabuleiro não deveria estar dividido em 8 dicionários diferentes. Porque não usar simplemente uma lista de listas?

Além disso, para denotar uma posição vazia, você está usando `[]`, que é uma lista vazia (e não uma string). Mas como as peças são strings, então por que não fazer a posição vazia ser uma string também? Poderia ser um espaço em branco, por exemplo (`' '`). Ficaria assim:

```
def setBoard():
    def peoes():
        return ['P'] * 8
    def pecas(): # desculpe, não sei se essa fileira tem um nome específico
        return ['T', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'T']

    # tabuleiro 8 x 8: é uma lista com 8 elementos, sendo que cada elemento é uma lista com 8 espaços em branco

    # primeiro cria as 4 fileiras vazias do "meio"
    tabuleiro = [[' '] * 8 for _ in range(4)]
    # white
    tabuleiro.insert(0, pecas())
    tabuleiro.insert(1, peoes())
    # black
    tabuleiro.append(peoes())
    tabuleiro.append(pecas())
    return tabuleiro

def imprime(tabuleiro):
    def separador():
        print('+'.join(['---'] * 9))

    def letras():
        print(' ', ' | '.join(chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(8)), sep='', end=' |\n')
        separador()

    letras()
    i = 7
    while i >= 0:
        linha = tabuleiro[i]
        print(' ', ' | '.join(linha), sep='', end='')
        print(f' | {i + 1}')
        separador()
        i -= 1

def mover(tabuleiro, colunaFrom, linhaFrom, colunaTo, linhaTo):
    def converteColuna(c): # converte a-h para 0-7
        return ord(c) - ord('a')

    colOrig = converteColuna(colunaFrom)
    linOrig = int(linhaFrom) - 1
    # move a peça para a nova posição
    tabuleiro[int(linhaTo) - 1][converteColuna(colunaTo)] = tabuleiro[linOrig][colOrig]
    # deixa a posição original vazia
    tabuleiro[linOrig][colOrig] = ' '

tabuleiro = setBoard()
while True:
    imprime(tabuleiro)
    piece = input("Deseja sair? s/n > ")
    if piece == 's':
        print('Adeus, obrigado por jogar.')
        break
    else:
        colunaFrom = input('Qual coluna você está? (a-h) ')
        linhaFrom = input('Qual linha você está? (1-8) ')
        colunaTo = input('Para qual coluna você vai? (a-h) ')
        linhaTo = input('Para qual linha você vai? (1-8) ')
        mover(tabuleiro, colunaFrom, linhaFrom, colunaTo, linhaTo)
```

Claro que há muito o que melhorar. Eu não verifico se as posições digitadas são válidas, nem se a posição de origem tem uma peça, ou se a posição de destino já está ocupada (sem contar que precisaria verificar se o movimento é válido para a peça escolhida, e só apresentar os movimentos válidos como opções, por exemplo).

Mas só de ter o tabuleiro mais organizado, já ajuda bastante. [Escolher a estrutura de dados adequada é meio caminho andado para um código melhor](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/163185).